# Running a real-time clock with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope

Now that I was helped getting AJAX running just great, I'm having problems running a clock function with it....

Clock code (located in the head):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ampm = "AM"; //Default
var message="";


function startTime()
{
var today = new Date(); //Number goes here
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
h=checkTime2(h);
document.getElementById('clocktxt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s+ " " +ampm + " " + message;
//t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
message = "How long you gonna sit there?";
  }
return i;
}

function checkTime2(i)
{
if (i>12)
  {
  i=i-12;
ampm="PM";
  }
return i;
}


//setInterval(startTime,1000);

</script>
```

AJAX code (bottom of the document):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function CheckForChange(){
    //alert("<?echo (count($listArray)) . ' and ' . count(file($filename_noformat))?>");
    //if (<?echo count($listArray)?> == <?echo count(explode("\n", $filename_noformat))?>){
        //setInterval("alert('Yup, it is 1')", 5000);

        //alert('Now it is changed');
    //}

    var ajaxReady = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxReady.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajaxReady.readyState == 4){
            //Get the data
            //document.getElementById('clocktxt').innerHTML = ajaxReady.responseText;
            //startTime();
            //alert("here");
            //alert(ajaxReady.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajaxReady.open("GET","ServerTime.php",true);
    ajaxReady.send(null);
}

setInterval(CheckForChange(), 1000);
setInterval(startTime(),1000);
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is pass the input from ServerTime.php which is just a count of milliseconds from Unix epoch, into the clock, so the clock is being updated by the AJAX every second and the clock function runs with a new starting value each second.... I used to have parameters for the clock function before I realized the clock wasn't even getting called.

What do you think is wrong? I'm guessing it has something to do with the clock and the caller of the clock being in two different script tags, but I can't think of how to get around it. For some reason when I moved the AJAX part into the same script tag, following the clock, nothing happens.

To Kolink: I have this

```
function getTheNow(){
TIMESTAMP = <?php echo time(); ?>000;
    offset = new Date().getTime()-TIMESTAMP;
    setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        now.setTime(now.getTime()-offset);
        // print out the time according to the variable `now`
//alert(now);
    },5000);
return now;
}


function startTime()
{
var now = getTheNow;
//alert(now);
var today = new Date(); //Number goes here
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
h=checkTime2(h);
document.getElementById('clocktxt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s+ " " +ampm + " " + message;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
message = "How long you gonna sit there?";
  }
return i;
}

function checkTime2(i)
{
if (i>12)
  {
  i=i-12;
ampm="PM";
  }
return i;
}


setInterval(startTime,1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer clocks are not so inaccurate that you have to re-sync them every second. Try every ten minutes, or even every hour.

In fact, I just do away with synchronising altogether. It is far easier to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    TIMESTAMP = <?php echo time(); ?>000;
    offset = new Date().getTime()-TIMESTAMP;
    setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        now.setTime(now.getTime()-offset);
        // print out the time according to the variable `now`
    },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this looks like a very nice script, but I can't figure out how to make it work, can you expand how make it work with the clock?

Comment: You already have code to take a `Date` object and put the time in the box. Just use that code, but this thing to get the time itself.

Comment: Easier said than done it's turning out...I've run into a lot of problems trying to get this to work...I have this....I've edited the original post to fit it in. I've tried a few different things. I always either get NaN, the clock won't show, or even the entire "source" of the getTheNow function instead of just the now variable......the times where I've gotten the "now" to appear correctly in an alert box, I've copied and pasted the static value in the date object, and it seems to work fine, but it requires quotes

Comment: And I've tried adding quotes around the now variable like this ("'" + now + "'"); but it doesn't seem to work...any ideas?

Comment: I did not put my code in a function. That's because it should be called once, and once ONLY. Replace the comment with whatever code you need to take `now` and use it.

Comment: When I searched in Google "ajax clock" - I've found this first link in it - with no AJAX here in this "good answer" (but which didn't work as mentioned in comments).

Comment: @Xsi This code works perfectly well, provided you have the basic programming skill to copy-paste it properly.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript 101 error

```
setInterval(CheckForChange(), 1000);
setInterval(startTime(),1000);
```

You are not assigning the function, you are calling/executing them and saying what ever is returned from these functions should be set. Drop the () so you are referencing the functions.

```
setInterval(CheckForChange, 1000);
setInterval(startTime,1000);
```

Comment: Hey I tried this and it worked, but sometimes it wants () which is weird... either way it looks like because it works I may've overloaded my host's processor or something because I got the Resource Limit Hit message and I can't try anything for an hour

Comment: Because you are making to many calls to the server. :) That is why this design is BAD.