# PHP/AJAX/Javascript Display website "age"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, countdown

I would like to display my website age but as a live result (like a reverse countdown via AJAX or so). Right now I have a PHP script that looks like:

```
<?php
echo secondsToTime(time()-(1203234532)); # number = timestamp when website was created
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
$dtF = new DateTime("@0");
$dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
php>
```

Now the actual age is displayed everytime the website is reloaded but how can I make it live?

Greetings

Comment: what do you mean by "live"

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612527/running-a-real-time-clock-with-ajax) or [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) might help.

Comment: Yeah What do you mean by "live" crackfreak. Does that function work?

Comment: Look at the setTinveral or setTimeout commands. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Comment: @jeff above meant to say `setInterval`.

Comment: @halfer fat fingers strike again LOL